# Installing Android Marshmallow on a Nexus device

Tags: android

I want to test out my app on a device running Marshmallow. From my understanding, this should be possible on a Nexus 5, 6 or 9 device. To install this, do you have to use the update feature on the device to get the newest version or can you use the Android SDK to install an image?

Comment: You can run on it emulator with Marshmallow, I just did it today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented at length in [the M preview documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html).

At a high level:

1. [Download the appropriate system image here](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html#images).
2. Reboot into the bootloader with `adb reboot bootloader`
3. Run `fastboot oem unlock`
4. Navigate to wherever you unzipped the system image and run `flash-all`
5. Run `fastboot oem lock`